# View Cart button not showing cart on Shopify

Tags: shopify, cart, drawer, ajaxify

https://imprint-aftercare.myshopify.com/
Built a theme using Timber as a basis.  Clicking 'Add to cart" successfully adds to cart and populates the slide out drawer with the cart.... however, clicking on the Cart icon makes the drawer slide out, but doesn't show the cart at all.  I've gone over this code dozens of times and compared to a store I've coded where this worked, but cannot figure it out.  HELP!

EDIT: as requested, here is the relevant code

```
<div id="CartDrawer" class="drawer drawer--right">
    <div class="drawer__header">
      <div class="drawer__title h3">your cart</div>
      <div class="drawer__close js-drawer-close">
        <button type="button" class="icon-fallback-text">
          <span class="icon icon-x"></span>          
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="CartContainer"></div>
</div>





{{ 'footer.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'fastclick.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'timber.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{% include 'ajax-cart-template' %}
{{ 'ajax-cart.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    ajaxCart.init({
      formSelector: '#AddToCartForm',
      cartContainer: '#CartContainer',
      addToCartSelector: '#AddToCart',
      cartCountSelector: '#CartCount',
      cartCostSelector: '#CartCost',
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }}
    });
  });

 jQuery('body').on('ajaxCart.afterCartLoad', function(evt, cart) {
    // Bind to 'ajaxCart.afterCartLoad' to run any javascript after the cart has loaded in the DOM
    timber.RightDrawer.open();
   ajaxCart.init({
      formSelector: '#AddToCartForm',
      cartContainer: '#CartContainer',
      addToCartSelector: '#AddToCart',
      cartCountSelector: '#CartCount',
      cartCostSelector: '#CartCost',
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }}
    });
  });
```

Comment: I can't see your site. It's password protected.

Comment: Shoot, let me fix that briefly.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything inside your #CartContainer div - which I assume is where the cart data is supposed to be displayed - so I guess it could be a liquid problem, so post your code and I'll take a look